# Install java on a wine in a linux terminal server

Tags: command-line, wine, java, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows terminal process (which requires Java). I need to run this in a Linux terminal server (it's an Amazon EC2 instance). I installed Wine, but now I need to install Java. When I try to run `wine jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe` it shows the following error:

```
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

How can install Java in Wine without installing the Xserver?

Comment: Most installer have an option for headless installations. Have you tried using that?

Comment: @DavidFoerster You saved the day. I had to add a'/s' and it installed properly. I was unaware of this option for java installation